# How to work with big json file (in vue project)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

**What I'm building**
There is this game Path of Exile, that has a passive tree that i'm recreating in my Vue application with some help from Pixi Js. The game developers release a json with the data for this passive tree every expansion for people to work with.

The Tree: https://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree
The json: [shorturl.at/gBSV5](http://shorturl.at/gBSV5)  (Don't forget to press the "View raw" link)

**My problem**
I got the tree component working, but since the json is quite large the app.js is also very large when i build for production. This is not that great for the performance and i'm looking to improve this.

[image]

**Vue Project**
My tree component looks something like shown below. So i'm using the json file to do various things so i can draw the tree on my canvas correctly.

```
import json from "@/data/data.json"
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

export default {
  name: "Tree",
  data() {
    return {
      treeData: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.treeData = json
    this.drawTree()
  },
  methods: {
    drawTree () {
      // Calculate size of the tree
      // Make some containers
      // Loop all nodes on the tree and draw them
      // Calculate connections between nodes and draw them
      // Some more stuff...
    }
  }
}
```

**The solution?**
I'm accessing the data from the json all the time in my code, so i don't really know where i can win performance if in the end i need all the data and this all will be in my app.js. So how should i go about working with this data? Is it maybe better to store it in a (mongoDB) database or would that result in the same problem?

Comment: I assume you will want to render the whole tree and not just parts of it right? Also are there parts of your app that don't use this data(such as landing page, maybe gear section...)?

Comment: Hi NeVo. I want the whole tree yes. For now the app will have 2 pages, a landing page and a page with a tree on it, the landing page will indeed not need this data.

Comment: You could try using [message pack](https://msgpack.org/index.html#:~:text=MessagePack%20is%20an%20efficient%20binary,addition%20to%20the%20strings%20themselves.) instead of JSON. Also, since poe only updates the tree every 3 months make sure you cache it in browser. If you don't need the tree to be interactive you could try a simmilar approach to the tree viewer at poe.ninja

Comment: Thanks Exile! I'll have to look into message pack and cashing! Also i was think, after reading your comment, that it might be a idea to just draw the tree and get rid of the data. I still need some of the data but not all of it. does this sound like something that could work?

Comment: Your shorturl seems to be broken, at least for me. I'd try to restrain myself from bundling your data right into the app. Any update means you'd have to rebuild your app and also redeploy just for some json-updates :/ Have you thought about loading the json via a http request (axios, fetch)? This way you could also let mobile users have a button "Load data" or something so they don't have to load several MB right away without their knowledge - for all those people without unlimited data. It's a quite different approach than yours right now but maybe worth thinking about it

Comment: Hi discolor! This helped a lot (in bundle size). Lighthouse score went from 35 to 85 also, not sure how important that is but i guess this is better. I feel like i still can improve more, my bundled component.js is still almost 600kb and chunk-vendors 230kb so i need to play around with that. Also like the idea you gave for mobile users, definitely going to do something with that!

Comment: @nevo your comment saved me! thanks!!! msgpack for the win!